# Registering output to stdout through wcf in IronPython?

Tags: wcf, ironpython

Is it possible to register the console output of a client through a server. I'm assuming this can be done through a NetworkStream?

Right now, I register the output of a desktop app to stdout through the SetOutput method provided inside Runtime.IO of IronPython. This method accepts a Stream as an arugment but the problem is how can I send that data back to the client through a stream from wcf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved like this :

I have a Memory stream on the server which compiles and executes the code then reads the data from the stdout and sends it back to the client.